# expand two divs similar to the divs in wordpress dashboard

Tags: html, css

I have two divs on a page with the same height position. I'm trying to make them expandable, allot like what goes on in the WordPress dashboard area:

[image]

Now i've got the left div to expand but only with the right div staying at the same width. I need both to expand on zooming in and out.

any ideas how this is done?

I've been looking it up for the past hour but i cant find anything.

A link to a tutorial would be cool (good luck finding one).

**EDIT:**

Here guys, i found something similar: http://jsfiddle.net/Khez/2zLPF/embedded/result/

do you see how the two divs side by side expand? the green and blue ones...

Comment: Can you post your code or a working example.

Comment: I found something similar to what im looking for, ill edit the question.

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding your question. By expand, do you mean horizontally or vertically. Likewise, I'm not sure what you mean by 'zooming'.

Comment: I need to expand the two divs horizontally (expand the width of them). I've given a link in the question that has something similar to what i'm trying to do. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your divs to dynamically change depending on the width of their container, set the widths using percentages:

HTML:

```
<div class="column">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 50%; }
.column div { margin: 0 20px; /* Set the spacing between the cells */ }
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/F7h2C/

***NOTE**: Because you are setting the combined widths of the columns to 100%, you cannot add padding to `.column` if you want them to be on the same line. The inner div `wrapper` will allow you to add spacing between your two columns. You should apply all background attributes to `.wrapper`.*